# How to find an object from recursive array of objects that is matching with the id using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have data like below,

```
const items = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'item1',
        subItems: [{
            id: '1',
            name: 'subitem-1',
        }],
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'item2',
        subItems: [{
            id: '2',
            name: 'subitem-1',
        }],
    }
]
```

Now i want to find the subItem that matches with id 2. so from above data expected output is

```
{
    id: '2',
    name: 'subitem-1',
}
```

i have tried something like below,

```
const subItem = Items.find(
    (item: any) =>
        item.subItems &&
            item.subItems.some(
                (subItem: any) => subItem.id === '2'
            )
);
```

but this will return the item that contains the subItem with id = '2'.

how can i fix the above code such that i get the SubItem instead of item?

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Will there only ever be a single sub item with id of 2?

Comment: Could be there only exact one subItems or could it be more than one?

Comment: yes only one subitem with id of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following, which will search and return only the inner object that is found.

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "item1",
    subItems: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "subitem-1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "item2",
    subItems: [
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "subitem-1"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function innerFind(array, key, value) {
  for (const obj of array) {
    const item = obj.subItems.find((el) => el[key] === value);

    if (item != null) return item;
  }
}

console.log(innerFind(items, 'id', '2'));
```

You pass in your items array, the key you want to search for ('id'), and then the value you want to search for ('2'). This function will return the first sub item it finds that matches.